# Does chroot make the root directory unwritable in Freebsd 11?

Tags: permissions, freebsd

When a a directory is chroot in Freebsd 11 will the root directory write protected that is it won't be writable?

Answer (score 0):

When you `chroot` to a directory `/a`, your environment changes and for your session and your session only, from this moment on `/`=`/a`. But if you switch terminals and start a new session or even change to another active session, `/`=`/`. `chroot` is not a panacea, in fact it has very strict limitations. If, on the other hand, you had it called early in the start up process and started all services from this "chrooted" environment, then your actual `/` would not be writable for any intends and purposes.

Comment: If you have root access (UID 0) inside the chroot, you can trivially easy escape it by "chrooting up".  That's one of the reasons FreeBSD Jails were invented - they cannot be escaped.

Comment: I don't think this works any more. At least I cannot verify this in FreeBSD versions over 11. I prefer jails for their far superior functionality, but I don't think chroot is insecure.